# Uncaught TypeError in getting json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below the code is working but I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchname' of undefined

Why am I getting this error message? I do not know how to resolve this issue.

```js
var selectedVal = "calendar";
$.getJSON("/js/datas.json", function(jsonData) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= jsonData.nameSearch.length; j++) {
    if (jsonData.nameSearch[j].searchname == selectedVal) {
      var linkname = jsonData.nameSearch[j].namelink;
      alert(linkname);
    }
  }
});
```

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "nameSearch": [{
    "searchname": "calendar",
    "namelink": "holidays"
  }, {
    "searchname": "date",
    "namelink": "kilo"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Use `<` instead of `<=` in `for` loop condition.

Comment: Try to print the value of the variable, if you are getting fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `=` sign from **for loop**.

For loop should be like:

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.nameSearch.length; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `<` instead of `<=`.

***Reason:-***

Because `jsonData.nameSearch` indexs start from 0 like `0,1,.....so on`

when you are using `jsonData.nameSearch.length` it gives you 2.

So loop will become:-

`for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {`

but index 2  inside `jsonData.nameSearch` doesn't not exist at all. so you are getting error.

***So the solution is*** removed `=` from loop like below:-

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.nameSearch.length; j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be something like this.

```
function nameSearchIdx(jsonData, idx, checkValue) {
    if (jsonData.nameSearch[idx].searchname === checkValue) {
        var linkname = jsonData.nameSearch[idx].namelink;
        alert(linkname);
    }
}
var selectedVal = "calendar";
$.getJSON("/js/datas.json", function(jsonData) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonData.nameSearch).forEach(function (val, idx, array) {
     if(!isNaN(val)) {
         nameSearchIdx(jsonData, idx, selectedVal);
     }
   });
});
```

```js
var jsonData = {
  "nameSearch": [{
    "searchname": "calendar",
    "namelink": "holidays"
  }, {
    "searchname": "date",
    "namelink": "kilo"
  }]
};
function nameSearchIdx(jsonData, idx, checkValue) {
if (jsonData.nameSearch[idx].searchname === checkValue) {
      var linkname = jsonData.nameSearch[idx].namelink;
      alert(linkname);
}
}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonData.nameSearch).forEach(
  function (val, idx, array) {
      if(!isNaN(val)) {
          nameSearchIdx(jsonData, idx, "calendar");
    }
  }
);
```